# Change content of div when div contains div

Tags: jquery, html, click, traversal

I have a structure;

```
<p class = "foo">"sometext"</p>
<div class = "foo">
   <p class = "moo">"sometext"</p>
   <div class = "moo">
      <p class = "boo">"sometext"</p>
      <div class = "boo">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And from that structure i create a menu, when i click on the paragraph the corresponding div will show.

```
 $("p").click(function()
      {
          $(this).next("div").toggle(); 
                     #Code that adds a minus sign before the paragraph eg. "+Mylink to "-Mylink"
       });
```

I im now trying to get a '+' sign if the menu is not pressed and '-' if not. The problem i have encounterd is a way of getting to know how to skip the the last step (class boo), it wont be needing any extra sign (it is not a menu). Any easy way traverse throught the structure and to add the plus-sign? Is there any easy way of getting the click function to know its expanded/de-expanded?

Comment: `<p = "foo">` is wrong, is perhaps the `class` attribute missing?

Comment: Just a typo, thanks for notice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:has()` selector to check for siblings:

```
$('div:not(:has(*))').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('-');
});
```

This should work:

```
$('p').prepend('<span class="toggle">-</span>');

$("p").click(function() {
  var sign = $(this).siblings('.toggle');

  $(this).next("div").toggle();

  if (sign.text() == '+') {
    sign.text('-');
  } else {
    sign.text('+');
  }
});
```

Comment: Or simply `div:not(:has(div))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. how to i change the content to p in the click function. I guess its something in the line with $(this).text(this); but i do not get it to work.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I im trying to ad a '-' sign when the menu is expanded. So i want something in style with $(this).text('-' + (this).text()); within the click function. the code above returns -[object HTMLParagraphElement], i have tried (this).text() with no luck.

Comment: From where are you calling `this`? Can you post *all* of your code? Edit it into your question.

Comment: Now i have edited it, i jsut want to get the content from the p. I guess it would be something stupid i im doing wrong.

Comment: Solved it $(this).text('-' + $(this).text());

Comment: Thaks for the answer.:) If i would like to traverse throught the div-structure and make the changes, like the first one you posted. Any easy way doing that, i have tried but failed to many times now ;)

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm not really seeing what else you could need from that sort of script.

Comment: I have a menu in the form described above. I now want to traverse througth the list adding a letter (+ sign) att the first poition at each menuitem unless its a the most inner one. Its quite hard to do this when the menu is created so i thougth it might be esiser to just traverse throught the structure as a last step.

Answer (score 0):

Given your HTML the simplest thing to do is to change the first selector to

```
$("p:not(.boo)").click(function() {
    // ....
})
```